# Serverless image handler returns error on non-image files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I've deployed the AWS Cloud formation [Serverless image handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/template.html) to resize images in an S3 bucket which is working well. It is using Cloudfront, API Gateway, Lamdba, and a custom domain.

Hosted within the same bucket are audio files. Now when I hit the Cloudfront URI for the audio files I receive at 502 error with a JSON response "Internal server error". Original image paths continue to work well.

I'd like to ignore (one way or another) all non-image files. One way that I have been attempting is to add a prefix to the `GET` request for media files. eg: `/media/{s3-key}`. But I am having difficulty getting that working and am thinking there must be another way.

For example: why would there be a 502 error if the image processing prefixes (`/fit-in/400x400/{s3-key}` for example) not be present? Why would Lambda be trying to process those rather than just returning?

Or even if the request makes it to Lambda: why fail rather than returning the file?

Comment: Possibly related https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler/issues/33

Comment: And probably https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler/pull/36/files

Comment: Hey thanks. The path is correct though. If I work around cloud front, and use the S3 URL directly, the file returns correctly. And images, unaltered and altered, are all fine. So something must be funny with the lambda script.

Comment: I think you should create another CloudFront Distribution using the same bucket as Origin Domain Name